# Nginx-redis server setup 502 bad gateway error

Tags: nginx, redis, openresty

on cloud VM
I set this nginx.conf file with redis and openresty

my_nginx.conf -

```
worker_processes 1;
error_log logs/error.log;
events{
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
 server {
     listen 8080; 
     location / {
       redis2_query set hello world;
       redis2_query get hello;
       redis2_pass 127.0.0.1:6379;
     }
  }
}
```

I run this conf as

```
$nginx -p pwd/ -c my_nginx.conf
```

now when I visit the ip address of this vm in my local browser I get error

`502 bad gateway
openresty/1.5.12.1`

`http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/`

where am I making mistake?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure your nginx config is correct: `nginx -p pwd/ -c my_nginx.conf -t`
2. make sure your redis server is working: `redis-cli -p 6379`.
3. Check `error.log`.

I tested your conf and it works.